# How to select data in between 1 interval time as dynamic query

Tags: oracle-sqldeveloper

I have a task which runs below query in an hourly manner. This consumes a lot of time and is risky if querying is missed out. Can someone help me on optimizing the query to be dynamic so I won't have to edit the time and date every time?

```
    select ((
    select count(*) from table_a
    where column_a = some value
    and date between '23-NOV-15 05:00:00' and '23-NOV-15 05:59:59')
    +
    (select count(*) from table_b
    where column_b = some value
    and date between '23-NOV-15 05:00:00' and '23-NOV-15 05:59:59'))
```

Comment: MySQL or Oracle? Far from compatible when it comes to date/time.

Comment: i'm using sql developer. I was thinking of using below, but to no luck...

        between to_char(sysdate, 'HH24:MI:SS') and to_char(sysdate-(1/24), 'HH24:MI:SS');

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's a bit unclear what you're trying to accomplish but assuming the database is Oracle, try

```
... date >= trunc(sysdate ,'HH24') and date < trunc(sysdate + 1/24,'HH24')
```

the trunc function with 'HH24' as 2nd parameter will trunc the time of the execution to the hour and +1/24 will progress the sysdate by 1 hour. So if you schedule it to run every even hour, it will obviously start some fraction of second after the scheduled time. This anomalies will be truncated and you will get clean query.

If you need it to be i.e. hour that just passed it will be li